# Prove that there is no homomorphism from $Z_{16} \oplus Z_2$ onto $ Z_4 \oplus Z_4$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Prove that there is no homomorphism from $Z_{16} \oplus Z_2$ onto $ Z_4 \oplus Z_4$

**Attempt**: Suppose these exists a homomorphism $\Psi : (Z_{16} \oplus Z_2) \rightarrow (Z_4 \oplus Z_4) $

Then, since $\Psi$ is an onto homomorphism, this means :

$|Ker ~\Psi|= |Z_{16} \oplus Z_2|/|Z_4 \oplus Z_4| = 32/16 =2 ..........(1)$

(For any homomorphism $\Psi$ under additive binary composition, $\Psi $

But the following elements in the Set : $\{(0,0),(4,0),(8,0),(12,0)\}$ form a group $\subset Ker ~\Psi$ and order of this group is $4 \neq 2$ contrary to the conclusion in $(1)$

{This is because in case of groups under addition , if $\Psi$ be a homomorphism, then $\Psi(k) = k \Psi(1)$. Whenever $k$ is a multiple of $4$, in $Z_4 \oplus Z_4, \Psi[(k,0)]$ will reduce to $(0,0)$}
Hence $\Psi$ cannot be a homomorphism.

**Is this attempt correct?**

Comment: Why does the existence of a subgroup of order four contradict the conclusion that $|\operatorname{ker}\Psi| = 2$?

Comment: $|Ker \Psi|=2$, Hence, $Ker \Psi$ is a subgroup of $|Z_{16} \oplus Z_2|$ and can contain only $2$ elements. But, we have got a group which contains $4$ elements. So, isn't this a contradiction?

Comment: $\ker\Psi$ is one of potentially many subgroups.

Comment: Well, we also have subgroups that contain 1, 2, 4, 8 ... elements. That doesn't prove anything yet.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese   .. Does this mean that $Ker~ \Psi$ can be **many** subgroups but each subgroup should be of order $2$?

Comment: No, it means that $\ker\Psi$ is a subgroup, but it is not necessarily the only subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}_{16}\oplus\mathbb{Z}_2$, there could be (and there are) other subgroups. The existence of another subgroup tells you nothing in this situation.

Comment: @MarcinŁoś and Michael : But, $\{(0,0),(4,0),(8,0),(12,0)\}$ forms a group and $\subset$ $Ker ~\Psi$ . But, this can't be possible because $|Ker ~\Psi|=2$

Comment: Why is it contained in the kernel?

Comment: Well, if you can show this, then that's it. But it seems you have just stated it. Perhaps it's obvious, but I cannot see it immediately.

Comment: That's because in case of groups under addition , if $\Psi$ be a homomorphism, then $\Psi(k) = k \Psi(1)$. Whenever $k$ is a multiple of $4$, in $Z_4 \oplus Z_4, \Psi[(k,0)]$ will reduce to $(0,0)$

Comment: I just have a query in this regard i.e. whether the above step is legal or not. It does seem to me though

Comment: Yes. This is correct. Do make it clear (in the solution that you present to your teacher/students) that you are using the fact that if $f:G\to G'$ is a homomorphism of abelian groups such that $ny=0$ for all $y\in G'$ for some fixed integer $n$, then $nG=\{nx\mid x\in G\}$ is automatically a subgroup of the kernel. I see that you edited just that in while I was thinking/typing :-)

Comment: Jyrki Lahtonen If I write like this will it be false? " Let f be one such onto homomorphism. It follows that f is 1-1 and hence $Z_{16}\times Z_2\simeq Z_4\times Z_4$ which is contradiction". I am unable to understand if it is wrong